# How to add elements in list which is value of dictionary and those elements not be repeated as another keys of that dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Suppose I have one list which contains anagram strings. For example,

```py
anList = ['aba','baa','aab','cat','tac','act','sos','oss']
```

And I want to construct a dictionary which contains element of that list as key and anagram strings of that element will be values of that key as a list, Also elements  which will be added into list are not repeated as another key of that dictionary. For example, if 'baa' has added to list, which list is value of key 'aba', then 'baa' can not be added as key further. Output dictionary should be look like,

```
anDict = {'aba' : ['baa','aab'],'cat' : ['tac','act'],'sos' : ['oss']}
```

I have tried with many approaches, but problem is that added elements in list are again add as key of dictionary.

How can I done it?

Comment: Can your list have any repeating elements?

Comment: No, there is no repeating elements in list. @Ayxan

Comment: Are the anagram-groups always adjacent to each other? (e.g. is `['aba','baa','aab','cat','tac','sos','act','oss']` possible?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can group your words by the count of letters using the Counter object:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

sorted list = sorted(anList, key=Counter)
groups = [list(y) for x, y in groupby(sortedList, key=Counter)]
#[['aba', 'baa', 'aab'], ['cat', 'tac', 'act'], ['sos', 'oss']]
```

Now, convert the list of lists of anagrams into a dictionary:

```
{words[0]: words[1:] for words in groups}
#{'aba': ['baa', 'aab'], 'cat': ['tac', 'act'], 'sos': ['oss']}
```

Comment: What! Didn't know that a datatype like `Counter` can be used as a key!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh It is used as a sorting key, not as a dictionary key. All anagrams by definition have the same letter counter.

Comment: Yes I actually meant to say sorting key! Okay since they have same letter counter it groups them accordingly

Comment: Yes It works perfectly fine, But there is one issue. If these anagram words are not adjacent to each other in list, then it will add new keys for those nonadjacent words even if they are anagram to each other.

Comment: Sorry, the list must be sorted first. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answers from [@DYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4492932/dyz) and [@AnttiHaapala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala) handle the expected output posted in the question much better than this one.

Following is an approach that comes with some caveats using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Sort each list element to compare it to the anagram key and append any anagrams that are not the same as the key.

```
from collections import defaultdict

anagrams = ['aba','baa','aab','cat','tac','act','sos','oss']

d = defaultdict(list)
for a in anagrams:
    key = ''.join(sorted(a))
    if key != a:
        d[key].append(a)

print(d)
# {'aab': ['aba', 'baa'], 'act': ['cat', 'tac'], 'oss': ['sos']}
```

Caveats:

- always uses the ascending sorted version of the anagram as the dict key, which is not an exact match for the example output in the question
- if the ascending sorted version of the anagram is not in the list, this approach will add a previously non-existent anagram as the dict key

Comment: And this would fail if it was `sos`, `sso`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - good point, if the ascending sorted version of the anagram is not in the list, this approach will add a previously non-existent anagram as the dict key (resulting in more keys / values than there were elements in the original list).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `groupby()` on a presorted list. The function `sorted` (or `Counter`) can be used as the key for sorting and grouping:

```
from itertools import groupby

anList = ['aba', 'baa', 'aab', 'cat', 'tac', 'act', 'sos', 'oss']

{k: v for _, (k, *v) in groupby(sorted(anList, key=sorted), key=sorted)}
# {'aba': ['baa', 'aab'], 'cat': ['tac', 'act'], 'sos': ['oss']}
```

Comment: @TrebledJ I thought about sets as well. But if there are words, which have different numbers of equal letters, you get a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here combining both the order of occurrence with the possibility of them not being grouped together:

```
anagram_list = ['cat','aba','baa','aab','tac','sos','oss','act']

first_anagrams = {}
anagram_dict = {}

for word in anagram_list:
    sorted_word = ''.join(sorted(word))
    if sorted_word in first_anagrams:
        anagram_dict[first_anagrams[sorted_word]].append(word)
    else:
        first_anagrams[sorted_word] = word
        anagram_dict[word] = []

print(anagram_dict)
```

The output is

```
{'aba': ['baa', 'aab'], 'sos': ['oss'], 'cat': ['tac', 'act']}
```

where the key is always the first anagram in order of occurrence, and the algorithm is strictly `O(n)` for `n` words of neglible length.

---

Should you want all anagrams in the list including the first one, it becomes much easier:

```
anagram_list = ['cat','aba','baa','aab','tac','sos','oss','act']

first_anagrams = {}
anagram_dict = defaultdict(list)

for word in anagram_list:
    anagram_dict[first_anagrams.setdefault(''.join(sorted(word)), word)].append(word)
```

The result is

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, 
    {'aba': ['aba', 'baa', 'aab'], 'sos': ['sos', 'oss'], 'cat': ['cat', 'tac', 'act']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is slow, but working code:

```
anList = ['aba', 'baa', 'aab', 'cat', 'tac', 'act', 'sos', 'oss']
anDict = {}
for i in anList:
    in_dict = False
    for j in anDict.keys():
        if sorted(i) == sorted(j):
            in_dict = True
            anDict[j].append(i)
            break
    if not in_dict:
        anDict[i] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `else` with a for loop to achieve this:

```
anList = ['aba','baa','aab','cat','tac','act','sos','oss']
anDict = dict()

for k in anList:
        for ok in anDict:
            if (ok == k): break
            if (sorted(ok) == sorted(k)):
                anDict[ok].append(k)
                break
        else:
            anDict[k] = []

print(anDict)
# {'aba': ['baa', 'aab'], 'cat': ['tac', 'act'], 'sos': ['oss']}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple version without itertools.

Create a multimap `sorted string -> [anagram string]`:

```
>>> L = ['aba', 'baa', 'aab', 'cat', 'tac', 'act', 'sos', 'oss']
>>> d = {}
>>> for v in L:
...     d.setdefault("".join(sorted(v)), []).append(v)
...
>>> d
{'aab': ['aba', 'baa', 'aab'], 'act': ['cat', 'tac', 'act'], 'oss': ['sos', 'oss']}
```

Now you've grouped the anagrams, use the first values as key of the return dict:

```
>>> {v[0]:v[1:] for v in d.values()}
{'aba': ['baa', 'aab'], 'cat': ['tac', 'act'], 'sos': ['oss']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
anList = ['aba', 'baa', 'aab', 'cat', 'tac', 'act', 'sos', 'oss']

anDict = {}
for word in anList:
    sorted_word = ''.join(sorted(word))
    found_key = [key  for key in anDict.keys() if sorted_word  == ''.join(sorted(key))]
    if found_key:
        anDict[found_key[0]].append(word)
    else:
        anDict[word]=[]


>>> anDict
{'aba': ['baa', 'aab'], 'cat': ['tac', 'act'], 'sos': ['oss']}
```